# Can you stack Nature's Balm?

Tags: monsters-den

In the game [Monsters' Den](http://www.kongregate.com/games/garin/monsters-den) is it possible to stack the +10 hp regen per turn bonus you get from the rangers skill "Nature's Balm"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, for anyone who is interested, is no.
It only stacks once.